# calling of javascript function inside of class

Tags: javascript, function

I have javascript class specified as :

```
var this_plugin_url = ''
...
function googleMapControls( Params ) {
    this_plugin_url = Params.plugin_url;
    ...
}

googleMapControls.prototype.showFiltersPopup= function() {
    ...
}
```

I can call functions from other js-script like :
...

```
var l_objgoogleMapControls = new googleMapControls( { } );
l_objgoogleMapControls.showFiltersPopup(); // that works ok,
```

But I get error when I call showFiltersPopup from other googleMapControls function like :

```
googleMapControls.prototype.showDirectionsPopup= function() {
        ...
        this.showFiltersPopup("block") // error Uncaught TypeError: this.showFiltersPopup is not a function(anonymous function) @ google_map_controls.js?ver=4.2.4:130
```

similar error when I call as :

```
googleMapControls.showFiltersPopup()
```

Which is the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error says `anonymous function` which indicates that most likely that code is executed inside a callback of async operation and thus `this` context is lost.

As a common work-around you should use closure. Declare a reference to `this` and use it inside callback

```
googleMapControls.prototype.showDirectionsPopup= function() {
     ...
     var self = this;
     asyncOperation(function(){
        ...        
        self.showFiltersPopup("block")
```